# Libraries for Online learning

Tags: machine-learning, online-algorithms

I am looking for packages (either in python, R, or a standalone package) to perform online learning to predict stock data.

I have found and read about Vowpal Wabbit (https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki),
which seems to be quite promising but I am wondering if there are any other packages out there.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to try Julia (or pyjulia for calling Julia from Python), there is [OnlineStats.jl](https://github.com/joshday/OnlineStats.jl).  The [StatLearn](https://github.com/joshday/OnlineStats.jl/blob/master/doc/StatLearn.md) type for statistical learning may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but...

**Liblinear (standalone)**

The authors recently released a new, faster version. A multi-threaded implementation is also available. [LIBLINEAR](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear/) is a linear classifier for data with millions of instances and features. It supports :

- L2-regularized classifiers
- L2-loss linear SVM, L1-loss linear SVM, and logistic regression (LR)
- L1-regularized classifiers
- L2-loss linear SVM and logistic regression (LR)
- L2-regularized support vector regression
- L2-loss linear SVR and L1-loss linear SVR.

**Sofia (R, standalone)**

Google released [Sofia](https://code.google.com/p/sofia-ml/), which is also callable from R through [RSofia](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSofia/index.html). It performs regressions, classification and ranking through:

- Pegasos SVM
- Stochastic Gradient Descent (SGD)
- SVM Passive-Aggressive
- Perceptron Perceptron with Margins
- ROMMA
- Logistic Regression (with Pegasos Projection)

There is an implementation of **online kmeans**, which is available in the source code, but not in the R package.

**Online random forests (Python, standalone)**

Some implementation of online random forests are available on git. To mention a few : [here is a C standalone implementation](https://github.com/amirsaffari/online-random-forests) and [here is a python implementation](https://github.com/balajiln/mondrianforest). Note that the theory is at its early stages, new implementations may come latter.

Comment: I doubt that LIBLINEAR can perform in online learning setting, as most of the tools in Sofia toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

The Weka library (implemented in Java) has support for online learning as well. The term Weka uses is "updateable classifier", that is, an algorithm that can learn from a single training instance, and it doesn't need the entire dataset to be available in memory.

Here's the [list of classifiers](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/UpdateableClassifier.html) supported, that are capable of online learning.